# Strange difference in cmd/bash/awk escape character requirement

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to run a rather strange looking command line on a couple of Windows systems and I expect to be able to use the same one on either Windows 7 with Git for Windows (GfW) or Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 running on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

The command line **naturally isn't** the one shown here, but the principle is the same. I need to make use of awk from Windows command line, I need to call awk from within bash to be able to reuse the same command line on both WSL and GfW and I need to make the whole call from within one and the same Command Prompt session.

On Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 running on Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```
cmd /c "echo Something strange is going on |bash -c "awk '{ print $1 }'""
Something strange is going on
```

Now, something made awk miss out on the $1 variable. I need to escape the dollar sign:

```
>cmd /c "echo Something strange is going on |bash -c "awk '{ print \$1 }'""
Something
```

That looks better, only the first word was output!

Now, same thing on Windows 7 with Git for Windows:

```
>cmd /c "echo Something strange is going on |bash -c "awk '{ print \$1 }'""
awk: cmd. line:1: { print \$1 }
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: { print \$1 }
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
```

Wait, what?! I can't use backslash to escape the dollar sign anymore! What's up with that? I need to remove it:

```
>cmd /c "echo Something strange is going on |bash -c "awk '{ print $1 }'""
Something
```

What am I doing wrong here? How come I need to escape the exact same command line differently depending on whether it's executed on Win7/GfW or Win10/WSL? I've tried escaping the command line with ^ as well, but as far as I can tell the dollar sign should not require that type of special attention for use with cmd.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really found a valid explanation for what is going on, but a simple workaround is to call Awk with a script file instead of using the command line, like so:

```
cmd /c "echo Something strange is going on |bash -c "awk -f script.awk""
```

where the script file simply contain the previous script (in reality more advanced):

```
{ print $1 }
```

At least that command line works without a hitch, on both Windows 7 with Git for Windows and Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 running on Windows Subsystem for Linux, and I don't have to worry much about escaping either...

Answer (score 0):

I think the special attention should go to the pipe symbol before the `bash`. Try escaping it with a caret `^|`.

Also there could be an issue with the nested double and single quotes. I do not know if they interfere when parsing. Maybe try replacing the outer one with backticks.